# Contact Group in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

Contact Groups in Microsoft Teams not populated when migrating from Skype for Business. Out of 300 users in office, only 1 user got all the contact groups populated, same as Skype for business groups.

Changed status of users from Island to Teams only but it is not making any difference

There is no error message, blank groups.